# Возможно ли сериализовать или конвертировать в Json непосредственно класс "GameObject"?

Tags: unity3d

Нужно сериализовать или конвертировать в Json с дальнейшей сериализацией (или как оно там работает) "GameObject", но сразу сериализовать невозможно, полагаю, потому что сам пробовал. В общем, в конечном итоге, хотелось бы иметь возможность не разбирать весь "GameObject".
Да, скорее всего, такое невозможно, но хочу увидеть однозначный ответ на этот вопрос, быть может окольными путями это возможно.

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите сериализовать у GameObject'а? У этого класса всего пара утилитарных полей.

Comment: В идеале всё, что имеет в себе "GameObject" в иерархии объектов, то есть, например, в открытое поле типа "GameObject" можно же передавать объект из иерархии и нужно сохранить весь этот объект со всеми дочерними объектами, но... полагаю, скорее всего, это невозможно, но всё же, быть может есть какой-либо способ

Comment: Никакого отношения к `Json` это не имеет. По сути вы пишите, что вам нужно создать `Prefub`. `PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset`.

Answer (score -1):

Unity по-своему хранит и обрабатывает GameObject'ы, поэтому их нельзя создать через `= new GameObject`, а только через `Instantiate`. GameObject хранит в себе только данные, нужные для юнити. Компонент Transform уже в свою очередь хранит положение в пространстве и иерархии. Если вы хотите сериализовать объект, то нужно сохранить просто данные об имени, position, rotation, scale, информацию о компонентах, которые в свою очередь можно сериализовать и такую же информацию по всем дочерним объектам. Потом можно будет создать такие же объекты по этой информации с помощью `Instantiate` и `AddComponent`.